# Static field and Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net

I have a static field in a non static class.

```
public class DBtools
{
     public static string ConString ="XXXXXXXXX";
}
```

This field is assigned to property in the code.

```
SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = DBtools.ConString;
```

But after i run this app I'm getting a error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

How come this is happening? It's a static field.

Comment: Are you sure `SqlDataSource1` has a value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SqlDataSource1 object has not been initialized.

Answer (score 2):

You have a debugger in front of you. Put a break point on that line, and when it stops investigate all the fields/variables/etc involved. It *sounds* like however `SqlDataSource1` is defined, it is currently `null`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the error is referring to `SqlDataSource1` being null?